Implicit differentiation of $\tan^{-1}(x^2y)=x+y^3$
I want to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ where $\tan^{-1}(x^2y)=x+y^3$. This is what I have tried:

Prep
$$\frac{d}{dx}\tan(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=\frac{\cos(x)\cos(x)-\sin(x)(\sin(x))}{\cos^2(x)}=1+\tan^2(x)=\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}=\sec^2(x)$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}y=\frac{d}{dx}\tan^{-1}(x)\implies\frac{d}{dx}\tan(y)=\frac{d}{dx}\tan(\tan^{-1}(x))\implies\frac{dy}{dx}\sec^2(y)=\frac{d}{dx}x=1\implies\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{\sec^2(y)}=\frac{1}{1+\tan^2(y)}=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

Method 1.1, use of $\frac{d}{dx}\tan^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$
$$\frac{1}{1+(x^2y)^2}\cdot\left(2xy+x^2\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=1+3y^2\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$\frac{2xy}{1+x^4y^2}-1=\left(3y^2-\frac{x^2}{1+x^4y^2}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{2xy}{1+x^4y^2}-1}{3y^2-\frac{x^2}{1+x^4y^2}}$$

Method 1.2, initial multiplication of $\left(1+x^4y^2\right)$
$$\left(\frac{1}{1+(x^2y)^2}\cdot\left(2xy+x^2\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=1+3y^2\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}\right)\cdot(1+x^4y^2)$$
$$2xy+x^2\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}=1+x^4y^2+3y^2\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}+3x^4y^4\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$\left(3y^2+3x^4y^4-x^2\right)\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}=2xy-x^4y^2-1$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2xy-x^4y^2-1}{3y^2+3x^4y^4-x^2}=\frac{-\left(-2xy+x^4y^2+1\right)}{3y^2+3x^4y^4-x^2}=\frac{1+x^4y^2-2xy}{x^2-3y^2-3x^4y^4}$$

Method 2, initial nesting of $\tan(x)$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\tan^{-1}(x^2y)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(x+y^3\right)$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\tan(\tan^{-1}(x^2y))=\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^2y\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\tan\left(x+y^3\right)$$
$$2xy+x^2\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}=\sec^2(x+y^3)\cdot\left(1+3y^2\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$$
$$2xy+x^2\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}=\sec^2(x+y^3)+3y^2\sec^2\left(x+y^3\right)\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$\left(x^2-3y^2\sec^2(x+y^3)\right)\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}=\sec^2\left(x+y^3\right)-2xy$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\sec^2\left(x+y^3\right)-2xy}{x^2-3y^2\sec^2\left(x+y^3\right)}$$

My question / concern:
$$\frac{\frac{2xy}{1+x^4y^2}-1}{3y^2-\frac{x^2}{1+x^4y^2}}\stackrel{?}{\equiv}\frac{1+x^4y^2-2xy}{x^2-3y^2-3x^4y^4}\stackrel{?}{\equiv}\frac{\sec^2\left(x+y^3\right)-2xy}{x^2-3y^2\sec^2\left(x+y^3\right)}$$

Prep
$$\begin{align}
\tan^{-1}(x^2y)=x+y^3 & \implies\tan(\tan^{-1}(x^2y)) & =\tan(x+y^3) \\
& \implies x^2y & = \tan(x+y^3) \\
& \implies\left(x^2y\right)^2 & =\tan^2(x+y^3) \\
& \implies x^4y^2 & = \tan^2(x+y^3) \\
& \implies 1+x^4y^2 & = 1+\tan^2(x+y^3) \\
& \implies 1+x^4y^2 & = \sec^2(x+y^3) \\
\end{align}$$

From LHS to RHS:
$$
\begin{align}\frac{\frac{2xy}{1+x^4y^2}-1}{3y^2-\frac{x^2}{1+x^4y^2}}& =\frac{\frac{2xy}{1+x^4y^2}-\frac{1+x^4y^2}{1+x^4y^2}}{\frac{3y^2\left(1+x^4y^2\right)}{1+x^4y^2}-\frac{x^2}{1+x^4y^2}}\require{cancel}\\
& =\frac{\frac{2xy-x^4y^2-1}{\cancel{1+x^4y^2}}}{\frac{3y^2+3x^4y^4-x^2}{\cancel{1+x^4y^2}}} \\
& = \frac{2xy-x^4y^2-1}{3y^2+3x^4y^4-x^2} \\
& = \frac{-\left(-2xy+x^4y^2+1\right)}{3y^2+3x^4y^4-x^2} \\
& = \frac{1+x^4y^2-2xy}{-\left(3y^2+3x^4y^4-x^2\right)} \\
& = \frac{1+x^4y^2-2xy}{x^2-3y^2-3x^4y^4} \\
& = \frac{\sec^2(x+y^3)-2xy}{x^2-3y^2\left(1-x^4y^2\right)} \\
& = \frac{\sec^2(x+y^3)-2xy}{x^2-3y^2\sec\left(x+y^3\right)}\qquad\blacksquare
\end{align}
$$

To obtain the first equality, find the common denominator and multiply numerator and denominator by $-1$.
For the second equality, since $\tan^{-1}(x^2y)=x+y^3$ you have $x^2y=\tan(x+y^3)$, and using the relation $\sec^2 u=1+\tan^2 u$ you get $1+x^4y^2=\sec^2(x+y^3)$.
